# Game Center Leaderboard not appearing on production version of game?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, game-center

My game went on the app store a few days ago and I cannot see my leaderboard at all.  It just says "no data available"

However, when I build my game directly to my phone using an ad hoc profile I'm seeing my beta player's scores..

[image]

My leaderboard is in the not live status.  I'm not sure if that matters or how to change that.  I have other games with a "not live" leaderboard that are working on production..

Should I delete and remake the leaderboard now that my game is actually up on the app store?

I cleared my test data.. no luck.

Do I just need to wait?  It's confusing.

I've called Apple support and theyre "working on it" but I feel like I'm stuck in a black hole now.. any way I can fix this myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]I'm not sure if this section existed before.  But I needed to explicitly add my created leaderboards to my release.